# PHP - Make outputted CMS content into a php variable

Tags: php, variables

I use Perch for CMS, and in order to output content, you put the following code in your page:

```
<?php perch_content('Phone Number'); ?>
```

However, I need to make the outputted content into a php variable, something like:

```
$phonenumber = perch_content('Phone Number');
```

I'm a complete php novice and I've tried a few things but nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$phonenumber = perch_content('Phone Number', true);
```

see http://docs.grabaperch.com/docs/content/perch-content/

It's always a good idea to look into documentations ;)

Answer (score 0):

For specific content I had to use:

```
perch_content('Events', array(
  'page' => '/sites/events.php',
  'skip-template' => true
  ));
```